# aiohttp TypeError: function() argument 'code' must be code, not str

Tags: python, typeerror, aiohttp

When a package (`pymodbus` in this case) tries to import `aiohttp` in any way:

```
import aiohttp
```

or, here:

```
from aiohttp import web
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/capstone2023/./modbus_server.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pymodbus.server import StartTcpServer
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymodbus/server/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from pymodbus.server.simulator.http_server import ModbusSimulatorServer
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymodbus/server/simulator/http_server.py", line 12, in <module>
    from aiohttp import web
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aiohttp/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .client import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 35, in <module>
    from . import hdrs, http, payload
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aiohttp/http.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .http_parser import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aiohttp/http_parser.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .helpers import NO_EXTENSIONS, BaseTimerContext
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aiohttp/helpers.py", line 667, in <module>
    class CeilTimeout(async_timeout.timeout):
TypeError: function() argument 'code' must be code, not str
```

Would anyone know why I am getting this error? I've installed these modules as per requirement 'pyModbus twisted pyyaml'.
The code is part of my uni project hosting a modbus server. The file was supplied as is I just had to install the modules and run the file but I get runtime errors.

`pip freeze` looks like this

```
adblockparser==0.7
AdvancedHTTPServer==2.2.0
aiocmd==0.1.2
aioconsole==0.3.1
aiodns==2.0.0
aiofiles==23.1.0
aiohttp==3.7.4
aiomultiprocess==0.9.0
aioredis==1.3.1
aiosqlite==0.17.0
aiowinreg==0.0.7
ajpy==0.0.4
alembic==1.8.1.dev0
altgraph==0.17.3
aniso8601==9.0.1
apispec==5.2.2
apispec-webframeworks==0.5.2
appdirs==1.4.4
APScheduler==3.9.1
asciitree==0.3.3
asgiref==3.6.0
asn1crypto==1.5.1
async-timeout==4.0.2
asysocks==0.2.2
attrs==22.2.0
autobahn==17.10.1
Automat==22.10.0
backcall==0.2.0
basemap==1.2.1
bcrypt==3.2.2
beautifulsoup4==4.11.2
bidict==0.22.1
binwalk==2.3.3
bleach==4.1.0
blinker==1.5
boltons==21.0.0
bottle==0.12.23
Bottleneck==1.3.2
Brlapi==0.8.3
Brotli==1.0.9
cairocffi==1.4.0
catfish==4.16.0
cbor==1.0.0
certifi==2020.12.5
cffi==1.14.5
chardet==4.0.0
CherryPy==8.9.1
click==8.1.3
click-plugins==1.1.1
click-spinner==0.1.10
colorama==0.4.6
configobj==5.0.8
constantly==15.1.0
crackmapexec==5.1.4.dev0
cryptography==3.3.2
cycler==0.11.0
Cython==0.29.24
dbus-python==1.2.18
debtags==2.1
decorator==5.1.1
defusedxml==0.7.1
deprecation==2.0.7
dicttoxml==1.7.15
distro==1.8.0
Django==3.2.18
dnslib==0.9.23
dnspython==2.0.0
docopt==0.6.2
dropbox==10.10.0
ecdsa==0.18.0
email-validator==1.3.0
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
ExifRead==3.0.0
faraday-agent-parameters-types==1.2.0
faraday-client==1.1.0
faraday-plugins==1.10.0
faradaysec==3.17.1
fastapi==0.63.0
feedparser==5.2.1
fierce==1.5.0
filedepot==0.5.2
filteralchemy==0.1.0
flasgger==0.9.5
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Classful==0.15.0.dev1
Flask-KVSession-fork==0.6.4
Flask-Limiter==1.0.1
Flask-Login==0.6.2
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-Principal==0.4.0
Flask-RESTful==0.3.9
Flask-Security-Too==4.0.0
Flask-SocketIO==5.3.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1
Flask-WTF==1.1.1
future==0.18.2
GDAL==3.2.2
geographiclib==1.52
geoip2==2.9.0
geojson==3.0.0
geopy==2.2.0
gitdb==4.0.9
GitPython==3.1.30
gnureadline==8.0.0
gpg===1.16.0-unknown
graphene==2.1.9
graphene-sqlalchemy==2.1.2
graphql-core==2.2.1
graphql-relay==2.0.1
h11==0.14.0
h2==4.1.0
hashID==3.1.4
hiredis==1.0.1
hpack==4.0.0
html2text==2020.1.16
html5lib==1.1
humanize==0.0.0
hupper==1.10.3
hyperframe==6.0.0
hyperlink==21.0.0
icalendar==4.0.3
idna==3.3
impacket==0.10.0
importlib-metadata==4.12.0
incremental==21.3.0
instagram-private-api==1.6.0.0
invoke==2.0.0
iptools==0.6.1
ipwhois==1.2.0
IPy==1.1
ipython==7.22.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
jdcal==1.0
jedi==0.18.2
Jinja2==2.11.3
jsonschema==3.2.0
kaitaistruct==0.10
kali-tweaks==2021.3.3
KismetCaptureFreaklabsZigbee==2018.7.0
KismetCaptureRtl433==2020.10.1
KismetCaptureRtladsb==2020.10.1
KismetCaptureRtlamr==2020.10.1
kiwisolver==1.3.2
ldap3==2.9.1
ldapdomaindump==0.9.3
lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings==1.2.2
limits==1.5.1
llvd==2.2.6
llvmlite==0.35.0
louis==3.19.0
lsassy==2.1.2
lxml==4.6.3
lz4==3.1.3+dfsg
macholib==1.16.2
Mako==1.2.4.dev0
Markdown==3.4.1
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
marshmallow==3.18.0
marshmallow-sqlalchemy==0.28.1
matplotlib==3.3.4
maxminddb==2.0.3
mechanize==0.4.8
minidump==0.0.21
minikerberos==0.2.0
mistune==2.0.4
mitmproxy==6.0.2
more-itertools==8.10.0
msgpack==1.0.2
msldap==0.4.7
multidict==5.1.0
mysqlclient==1.4.6
nassl==4.0.0
neo4j==5.2.dev0
neobolt==1.7.17
neotime==1.7.4
netaddr==0.8.0
netifaces==0.11.0
networkx==2.8.8
nplusone==1.0.0
ntlm-auth==1.4.0
numba==0.52.0
numexpr==2.7.3
numpy==1.19.5
odfpy==1.4.2
olefile==0.46
openpyxl==3.0.9
orjson==0.0.0
packaging==23.0
pandas==1.1.5
paramiko==2.12.0
parso==0.8.3
passlib==1.7.4
Paste==3.5.2
PasteDeploy==2.1.1
PasteScript==3.2.1
patator==0.9
pcapy==0.11.4
pefile==2023.2.7
pexpect==4.8.0
pgspecial==1.11.10
phonenumbers==8.12.57
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==8.3.0
plaster==1.0
plaster-pastedeploy==0.5
pluginbase==1.0.1
ply==3.11
prettytable==3.6.0
promise==2.3
prompt-toolkit==3.0.36
protobuf==3.12.4
psycopg2==2.8.6
ptyprocess==0.7.0
publicsuffix2==2.20191221
py-ubjson==0.16.1
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycairo==1.16.2
pycares==3.1.1
pycparser==2.21
pycryptodomex==3.11.0
pycurl==7.44.1
pydantic==1.10.4
PyDispatcher==2.0.5
pydot==1.4.2
pyee==9.0.4
pyExploitDb==0.2.6
pyfiglet==0.8.post0
Pygments==2.14.0
PyGObject==3.38.0
pygraphviz==1.7
PyHamcrest==2.0.3
pyinotify==0.9.6
PyInstaller==3.5+498e6ee058
pylnk3==0.2.1
pyminifier==2.1
pymodbus==3.2.2
pymssql==2.1.4
PyMySQL==1.0.2
PyNaCl==1.5.0
pyOpenSSL==21.0.0
pyotp==2.6.0
pyparsing==3.0.9
pypdf2==2.12.1
pyperclip==1.8.2
pypng==0.20220715.0
pyppeteer==1.0.1
pyproj==3.0.0
pypsrp==0.5.0
pypykatz==0.3.7
PyQRCode==1.2.1
PyQt5==5.15.6
PyQt5-sip==12.9.0
pyqtgraph==0.12.3
pyramid==2.0
pyrsistent==0.15.5
pyserial==3.5
pyShodan==0.2.6
pyshp==2.3.1
pysmi==0.3.2
pysnmp==4.4.12
PySocks==1.7.1
pyspnego==0.1.5
python-apt==2.2.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-debian==0.1.42
python-docx==0.8.11
python-engineio==4.3.4
python-magic==0.4.26
python-pam==2.0.2
python-pptx==0.6.18
python-snappy==0.5.3
python-socketio==5.7.2
PyTrie==0.4.0
pytz==2022.7.1
pywerview==0.3.3
pyxdg==0.28
PyYAML==5.4.1
qrcode==7.4.2
Quamash==0.6.1
redis==3.5.3
repoze.lru==0.7
requests==2.25.1
requests-file==1.5.1
requests-ntlm==1.1.0
requests-toolbelt==0.10.1
retrying==1.3.3
Routes==2.5.1
rq==1.12.0
ruamel.yaml==0.17.21
ruamel.yaml.clib==0.2.6
rule-engine==3.5.0
Rx==3.2.0
scapy==2.5.0
scipy==1.7.1
secure==0.3.0
selenium==4.0.0a1
service-identity==18.1.0
setproctitle==1.2.2
shodan==1.28.0
simplejson==3.17.5
simplekv==0.13.0
six==1.16.0
slowapi==0.1.4
smmap==5.0.0
smoke-zephyr==2.0.1
sortedcontainers==2.4.0
soupsieve==2.1
speaklater==1.4
SQLAlchemy==1.3.22
sqlalchemy-schemadisplay==1.3
SQLAlchemy-Utc==0.14.0
sqlparse==0.4.2
sslyze==5.1.1
starlette==0.14.1
stem==1.8.1
syslog-rfc5424-formatter==1.2.3
tables==3.6.1
tabulate==0.8.9
Tempita==0.5.2
termcolor==1.1.0
terminaltables==3.1.10
texttable==1.6.7
theHarvester==4.0.0
tld==0.11.11
tls-parser==1.2.2
tornado==6.2
tqdm==4.55.0
traitlets==5.5.0
translationstring==1.4
Twisted==22.4.0
txaio==21.2.1
typing-extensions==4.4.0
tzlocal==2.1
u-msgpack-python==2.3.0
ujson==4.0.2
unicodecsv==0.14.1
Unidecode==1.3.6
urllib3==1.26.2
urwid==2.1.2
uvicorn==0.17.6
uvloop==0.16.0
venusian==3.0.0
wafw00f==2.2.0
wapiti3==3.0.4
wcwidth==0.2.5
webargs==8.0.1
webencodings==0.5.1
WebOb==1.8.6
websocket-client==1.2.3
websockets==10.4
Werkzeug==2.2.2
wfuzz==3.1.0
whois==0.8
wifite==2.6.6
winacl==0.1.5
wsaccel==0.6.3
wsproto==1.2.0
WTForms==3.0.1
xcffib==0.11.1
xdg==5
xlrd==1.2.0
XlsxWriter==3.0.2
xlutils==2.0.0
xlwt==1.3.0
xmltodict==0.13.0
yara-python==4.0.4
yarl==1.6.3
yaswfp==0.9.3
zipp==1.0.0
zlib-wrapper==0.1.3
zope.deprecation==4.4.0
zope.interface==5.4.0
```

Comment: What is the output of `pip freeze`? Please [edit] your question and post the results there, not in the comments.

Comment: [Related Github issue](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/6794)

Comment: Just updated the question with the freeze output.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please include a [mre] that produces the error. The [tour] and [ask] are also good places to get started here.

Comment: seem to have fixed it after installing pip.

Comment: @CrazyChucky The MRE is to have an older version of `aiohttp` and `async-timeout`>=4, then run `import aiohttp`. When the OP installed pip and installed/upgraded `pymodbus`, `aiohttp` was upgraded to 3.8.3, which can work with `async-timeout`>=4, hence the error went away. This could actually be a useful post to people in the future, so I've edited the title to make it more clear and voted to reopen. I would urge you to vote to reopen as well.

Comment: @MattDMo Sounds good, would you like to edit the necessary info into the question?

Comment: @George in the future, I would look into virtual environments using the built-in [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) or one of the many available 3rd-party tools like [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) (not to be confused with the [`pip` package of the same name](https://pypi.org/project/pyenv/), which doesn't actually install the tool).

Comment: @CrazyChucky all set

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to install pip.

```
pip install pymodbus
```

---

Please note that this was due to `pymodbus`'s requirement for a newer version of `aiohttp`. The older version didn't work with `async-timeout` version 4. You had `aiohttp` 3.7.4 and `async-timeout` 4.0.2. This issue is exactly the same one as reported in the `aiohttp` repo [here](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/6794). Upgrading to `aiohttp` 3.8.3 fixed the dependency issue and the problem that was being experienced.